# Strange behavior in Grails database-migration plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, database-migration

I am using the database-migration plugin to control changes in my DB. I have followed this tutorial, step by step, to apply to my project. Everything seems to be OK, except the "dbm-gorm-diff" command.

First, I created a snapshot of my DB by using "grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy" command. Then I tried to modify a table (called Person table, add one more property) and run the "dbm-gorm-diff" command. But the diff file I received is too big. It is absolutely a new complete snapshot of my DB (including the new added column)! I expected that file just only shows what really changed in DB compared to the previous state.

So is that wrong? How can I make it work as I expected (and I think that is the correct way to produce the diff file). Could you please help me solve this? 
Thank you so much.

P/S: Because I have some errors when running the "dbm-gorm-diff" command, so I have applied this fix 
https://github.com/ph4t/grails-database-migration/commit/68fff38397157740ee4d993c8bb67811a0f021bb
to the database-migration plugin. It works OK but give me a strange diff file.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i will remove other changes on after updating a person class :

given that my first changlog.grovvy is there and then remove all other that the migration script write on your person-update-changelog.groovy for example.

And

Remain with only that say you column modifcations. It is a strange the updating for column size like a

```
       varchar(20) to varchar(25) in database ,and 

       String Name

       name(maxlenght:25)  //this a change
```

might not get generated for an update. I simple add

```
        sql('Alter table column ...')
```

to reflect the changes on database.So remove those generated codes which you dont understand and keep up the changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, I believe you may be running the steps out of sequence.  The dbm-generate-gorm-changelog compares your domain objects with the database and creates the initial change log.  Running the dbm-gorm-diff without applying the changes will result in essentially the same change log as you're seeing.  I believe the life cycle you want is...

1) Create your GORM objects.
2) Run dbm-generate-gorm-changelog
3) Run dbm-update to create your database schema objects

Then you iterate by making changes to your domain objects.

1) Modify GORM object
2) Run dbm-gorm-diff [some file name].xml -add
3) Run dbm-update
4) Repeat as necessary.

If you're actually not starting out with an empty database, than there are different targets to get you where you're going and the life cycle will be a bit different.

See http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/index.html for more detail.